# Android Studio is missing some attributes like fontFamily in Layout Editor mode

Tags: android-studio, button, layout, attributes, missing-features

after I've started using a new Windows 10 system and installed the latest version of Android Studio I've had some minor problems like missing attributes in the Layout Editor mode. I'm used to add some attributes through typing on XML edit, but as I tried to change the Font Family from a button using the Attributes side bar I couldn't find fontFamily anywhere! It wasn't in the textAppearance context and neither looking through the whole attributes list.

If I come to add the attribute by typing in XML it does appears on the side bar, but only and if I do that, otherwise I can't find it anywhere. I'm looking for a clue about this for some hours without any luck... anybody here nows anything about it?

The only thing I tried to "solve" this was renaming some folders like Cache, Compiler, Frameworks and some others at both, .android and .AndroidStudio3.3 folders. This didn't make the missing attributes show up.

[fontFamily as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLnLb.png)

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem.  Font family is missing.  I do use Windows 10.  Using Android 3.4, sadly, manually adding the attribute doesn't cause it to appear.

Comment: Weird.  Just installed Material theme plugin for Android Studio and fontFamily appears.  Not sure if reboot, material theme, previous manually adding attribute, or the gods jacking with me.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this when trying out Android Studio v3.4.1.

It turned out the default min SDK version was set to 15. Bumping it up to 16 made the attribute show up in the all the expected places!